# Load Account detail page in service console having multiple integration calls

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

We are trying to build a service console app for our agents. When the IVR call gets redirected to agent, the account details page get opened up via the CTI integration. However, we have several sections and related lists in the account details page that needs data from our backend on-prem systems. Now, what's the best way of accomplishing this in Lightning experience. Do I have to build a new lightning page with each section probably correlating to a lightning component that's going to fetch the data from the on-prem systems. Initially, I thought of implementing a service component and dropping that on the account detail page but was stuck as to how could I prevent the other parts of page from being loaded while this service component is going to make calls outs and get the required data and load that into my account record. In this use case, we are looking at least 8-10 sections (with each about 6-8 fields) in the account details and more than 80% of the fields are going to be fetched from the on-prem systems.

Is there anyway I can leverage any out of the box tools (similar to an extension in VF page along with standard controller) to get this info? or is building a new lightning page with each of the sections as lightning components to get this data.

Please share your guidance/thoughts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot build OOTB solution for your use case.

Best way to handle this use case using Asynchronous callouts (also referred to as Apex continuations) allow you to invoke long-running services without tying up server resources and running into Apex concurrency limits.

Since Lightning component doesn't support Continuation, so here is examples of doing this.

Refer [Invoking Apex Continuations from Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2017/09/invoking-apex-continuations-lightning-components.html)

Comment: thanks, but that would mean the UI would be rendered to the agent first and later refreshed once the data is refreshed and that would be an incorrect agent experience, isn't it?